# HTML Video won't play vtt subtitles

Tags: html5-video, webvtt

here's my HTML snippet:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="align-content:center;width: 50%;" >
    <video src="Big_Buck_Bunny_1080_10s_30MB.mp4" height="1000" width="1000" controls>
        <track default kind="subtitles" srclang="en" src="sample.vtt" label="subtitles">
    </video>
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

I've tried several VTT file but it dones't work.
On chrome it doesn't even display the subtitles track selection option while on firefox the subtitles are simply not played.

Anyone?
Thanks.